# Why If i dont declare @Service on my Service implementations can not make an @Autowired?

Tags: spring

Ive faced this issue lately, on all my services implementation, I need to use the @Service to later be able to autowired them. Why is this like this?

Am I missing a configuration or a missconfiguration? As far as I remember shouldnt be a must.

I have my component scan over the directory of services

Is there any way to use sort of `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"mypackage1", "mypackage2})` for this services without have to tag them as service?

Comment: COmponent scan works for detecting beans that are annotated with `@Component` or annotations like `@Service`, `@Repository` etc. if you don't put an annotation it will not be picked up as a component. Then register it as a bean in xml or java.

Comment: If i register them in a bean, Do I have to register each of all them? there is no option to say all classes from a package are services, components or repositories?

Comment: You can specify an include filter, but why don't you simply want to add `@Service`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have your service labelled with `@Service` (and any other extension of `@Component`), Spring can detect the class via component-scanning and automatically register it as an `@Bean`. Only `@Bean`s can be autowired. Without the appropriate annotation, Spring does not register the class as a bean.

An alternative is manually registering your service as a bean (in your Javaconfig)

```
@Bean
public MyService myService() {
  return new MyService();
}
```

Then your service will be able to be `@Autowire`d without annotating it appropriately.